# In a query of a sqlanywhere db the operator "AND" will not work with DQL or Query Builder

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, sqlanywhere

With mysql, oracle or mssql the query works without problems, with sqlAnywhere nothing is found !?

```
$TYP = 'INFO';
$LNG = 'ES';

$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM msgtxtp e WHERE e.msgtyp = :typ AND e.msglng = :lng Order BY e.msgtyp, e.msgnum');

$query->setParameters(array(
    'typ' => $TYP,
    'lng' => $LNG 
            ));

$result = $query->getResult();

            if (!$result) {

                echo 'Noting found!';


            } else {

                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    $TXT=$row->getMsgtxt();
                    echo $TXT . '<hr><br>' ;   
                }     

            }
```

Does anyone have also problems with queries on sqlAnywhere databases and find a solution?

Comment: invalid SQL.  SELECT e.*...

Comment: Hi! No it's not SQL, it's DQL in doctrine2.